# Need help when comparing strings

Tags: javascript, html

need help checking if a text contains a string to search for.

Say that I have a text

> "somerandomtextstringexampleexample_1"

And I want to compare with for example this String

> "example_1_e23wet_est1"

Now because the text contains **"example_1"** I want the function to return **"example_1"** and **not** also "example". (But if the string would have been "example_4_e23wet_est1" it should have returned just "example)

So the function takes 2 arguments

```
function searchForString(text,stringToCompare){
var foundstring;
...
if(foundstring)
return foundstring//In this case "example_1"
}
```

But then I'm pretty lost on how to carry on here since "indexOf" don't work here.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: You said: But if the string would have been "example_4_e23wet_est1" it should have returned just "example" . Shouldn't it have been "example_"? What you actually want is the largest substring of 2 strings right?

Comment: I think the problem that you are having is that your rules around what should match are very vague - for example what if your second string was `example_1somerando`?  You should precisely define the rules for your function and then have another go.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want the largest common substring, you might want to have a look here : [largest common substring implementation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#JavaScript) and at this [discussion about suffix tree for that matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896474/how-to-find-largest-substring-among-two-strings) :)

Answer (score 0):

Call **searchForString("somerandomtextstringexampleexample_1", "example_1_e23wet_est1")**;

It returns a list of matches. 
For example in this case: ["e", "ex", "example", "e", "example_1", "e"]...
Take the greatest.

```
function searchForString(text, searchString) {
    var i, max, match = '', matches = [], str;

    function matchingStr(string, searchString) {
        var i = 0, 
            j = 0, 
            matchStr = '',
            strLength = string.length,
            sstrLength = searchString.length;

        while (string[i] === searchString[j] &&
               i < strLength &&
               j < sstrLength) {

            matchStr += string[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }

        return matchStr;
    }

    for (i = 0, max = text.length; i < max; i++) {
        str = (i === 0) ? text : text.slice(i, max);
        console.log("str: " + str);
        console.log(match);
        match = matchingStr(str, searchString);    

        if (match.length !== 0) {
            matches.push(match);
        }         
    }    
  return matches;
}
```